# Reference Azure Storage user assigned identify with Azure Lock resources in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have Azure storage resource and it will create user managed identity as part of the storage recourse provision (Dynamic Block).
there is another resource with "azurerm_management_lock" to enable lock on relevant identity. I am trying to set the above mentioned Managed identity as a scope. But its keep failing.

Any idea why this isn't working ? seems Scope reference isn't working properly

```
**main.tf**
`resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  account_replication_type          = var.storage_account_account_replication_type
  account_tier                      = var.storage_account_account_tier
  location                          = var.storage_account_location
  name                              = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name               = var.storage_account_resource_group_name
  access_tier                       = var.storage_account_access_tier
  account_kind                      = var.storage_account_account_kind`

  dynamic "identity" {
    for_each = var.storage_account_identity == null ? [] : [var.storage_account_identity]
    content {
      type         = identity.value.type
      identity_ids = toset(values(identity.value.identity_ids))
    }
  }
}



`data "azurerm_storage_account" "identity" {
  name = azurerm_storage_account.this.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_storage_account.this.resource_group_name
 id = azurerm_storage_account.this

  
}

 resource "azurerm_management_lock" "storage_account" {
 count = var.lock_storage_account != null ? 1 : 0
 name = coalesce(var.lock_storage_account.name, "lock-${azurerm_storage_account.this.name}")
 scope = data.azurerm_storage_account.identity
 lock_level = var.lock_storage_account.lock_level

depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_account.this ]
   
 }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to Reference the Azure Storage user assigned to identify with Azure Lock resources in Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

Here issue is that the scope attribute of the **azurerm_management_lock** resource expects a full Azure Resource ID, but the code is trying to assign the **data.azurerm_storage_account.identity** as a scope, which is not a valid Azure Resource ID.

Here you also got below mentioned issues

There is no azurerm_storage_account.this in the code provided, yet it is referenced multiple times.
& In the data "azurerm_storage_account" "identity" block, the code is trying to assign an entire resource (azurerm_storage_account.this) to the id attribute, which is incorrect.

Here is the updated version of your requirement

**My terraform Configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = var.storage_account_resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example" {
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  name                = "${var.storage_account_name}-identity"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  account_replication_type = var.storage_account_account_replication_type
  account_tier             = var.storage_account_account_tier
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  name                     = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  access_tier              = var.storage_account_access_tier
  account_kind             = var.storage_account_account_kind

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.id]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_management_lock" "storage_account_lock" {
  count      = var.lock_storage_account != null ? 1 : 0
  name       = coalesce(var.lock_storage_account.name, "lock-${azurerm_storage_account.example.name}")
  scope      = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  lock_level = var.lock_storage_account.lock_level

  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.example]
}
```

##### variable.tf:

```
variable "storage_account_account_replication_type" {
  description = "The replication type for the storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "storage_account_account_tier" {
  description = "The tier for the storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "storage_account_location" {
  description = "The Azure location for the storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "storage_account_name" {
  description = "The name for the storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "storage_account_resource_group_name" {
  description = "The resource group name for the storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "storage_account_access_tier" {
  description = "The access tier for the storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "storage_account_account_kind" {
  description = "The kind for the storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "lock_storage_account" {
  description = "Lock configuration for the storage account."
  type        = map(any)
  default     = null
}


variable "storage_account_identity" {
  description = "Identity block for the storage account."
  type = object({
    type         = string
    identity_ids = list(string)
  })
  default = null
}
```

##### output.tf:

```
output "storage_account_id" {
  value       = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  description = "The ID of the created storage account."
}

output "user_assigned_identity_id" {
  value       = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.id
  description = "The ID of the created user assigned identity."
}

output "storage_account_lock_id" {
  value       = length(azurerm_management_lock.storage_account_lock) > 0 ? azurerm_management_lock.storage_account_lock[0].id : null
  description = "The ID of the created management lock on the storage account, if it was created."
}
```

##### terraform.tfvars:

```
storage_account_account_replication_type = "LRS"
storage_account_account_tier             = "Standard"
storage_account_location                 = "East US 2"
storage_account_name                     = "demoinstoragevk"
storage_account_access_tier              = "Hot"
storage_account_account_kind             = "StorageV2"

storage_account_identity = { type = "UserAssigned" identity_ids = ["<id1>", "<id2>"]

lock_storage_account = {
  name       = "mylock"
  lock_level = "CanNotDelete"
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment . But here will set lock only for Storage account. But there will be a Managed aIdentity object and it will not have Lock. I am trying to set the that identity object as a scope .

Comment: updated the solution as per your requirement

Comment: thanks for your comment . But still i see scope as "  scope      = azurerm_storage_account.example.id"  and not pointing the managed identity. I may miss something ? . Identity part is defined as a Dynamic block.

Comment: If your intention is to prevent accidental deletion or modification of the Storage Account (and thus its associated Managed Identity), you'd apply the lock to the Storage Account itself (which I had done previously with scope = azurerm_storage_account.example.id). If you wanted to apply a lock to a user-assigned Managed Identity, that would be a separate Azure resource, and you could apply a lock to that.